# Got Error When Add JWT in Solution then got error (HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

[image]In This code we configure jwt in start up file and jwt key and Issuer add in appsetting.json file
and got error added below.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
    {  
        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)  
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>  
        {  
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  
            {  
                ValidateIssuer = true,  
                ValidateAudience = true,  
                ValidateLifetime = true,  
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,  
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))  
            };  
        });  
        services.AddMvc();  
    }  

    [![AppSetting.Json
    {  
      "Jwt": {  
        "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",  
        "Issuer": "Test.com"  
      }  
    }]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/59sP5.png
```

Comment: Is your application inside an app. pool shared by other applications?In-process application can only be hosted in a dedicated app. pool.

Comment: When change into to appsetting.json file some syntax error that why get this type error   
      "Jwt": {  
        "Key": "ThisismySecretKey",  
        "Issuer": "Test.com"  
      }